# How do I insert data from parameters into a table with a trigger after Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am new to triggers, I am trying one that would let me insert the reasons for the update into a log table after another table was updated `updated`. The problem is that I am trying to make the user type an input as it would do in a stored procedure but that doesn't work with triggers apparently.

Let's say we have the table, `Users`:

```
User ID | User
--------+-------
   1      John
```

The result I want is the following:

```
Log_ID | Reason_Change
-------+------------------------------------------
   1     John wanted to change his name to John25
```

Is that possible?

I am trying:

```
@Reason_Change VARCHAR(500)
```

Comment: Triggers can't accept any parameters. They can only work with data that exists in the tables.

Comment: Then if i want to insert data, should i define a specific string in the trigger?

Comment: If you want that data hard coded then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this with an `instead of` trigger on a view.  The idea is the following:

1. Create a view that contains the columns from `users` along with the change reason.
2. Define an `instead of` trigger on the view.  This will allow an `insert` to include the change reason.
3. Only use the view for `insert`s.

Then, you can include the reason in the `insert`.  The trigger would put all the other columns in `users` and update the `logs` table appropriately.

Such triggers are explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx).